# How to change a varchar to date in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

I want to Convert a varchar column into datetime

i have a table which have a column created_at whose data type is varchar

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEbHW.png)

i am trying to change the datatype as datetime and using this query

ALTER TABLE user123 add COLUMN new_date DATE ;
UPDATE user123 SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') ;

but new column new_date returning null values

[Null values in new column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oxk0.png)

Comment: I get a truncation error when I try this , I suggest you include the time element in the str_to_date function and wrap in a DATE function to extract the date part.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the time part before passing the string to `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
UPDATE user123 
SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(created_at,1,10),'%d-%m-%Y');
```